# Make a batch that recognizes active powerplan and changes it

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch that will be assigned to a special button on the laptop which, hopefully, will swap between Balanced and Power-saver power plans. So, i want it to recognize if one of them is currently active and activate the other.

I have been looking for examples and my understanding on windows batch went as far as this non-working try:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('powercfg -getactivescheme') do @set var=%a
if "%var%"=="Power Scheme GUID: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e (Balanced)" (
    powercfg -s a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a
) else  (
    if "%var%"=="Power Scheme GUID: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a (Power saver)" (
        powercfg -s 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
    )
)
```

I am trying to execute the lines one by one but the if comparison does not seem to work as expected. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative workaround in just one line

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('powercfg -getactivescheme') do echo %a | find /i "balanced" > nul && powercfg -s a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a || powercfg -s 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
```

It works if you intend to switch between two states.

> Note: this works in commandline context. to include in batch-file
>   context change any *%a* to *%%a*
>
> && operator means *previous command successful*
>
> || operator means *previous command failed*

so *echo %a | find /i "balanced" > nul* searchs for the keyword *balanced*, if true, execute the command after &&, otherwise execute command after ||.

edit: minor changes needed. you have all you need...

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powercfg -getactivescheme') do (
  echo %%a | find /i "performance" > nul && exit/B
  echo %%a | find /i "balanced" > nul && powercfg -s a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a || powercfg -s 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works indeed. It just needs a minor change. I want to leave Performance plan untouched. Swap between Balance and Power-saver only if one of them is active. I want it to do nothing when Performance plan is active.

Comment: **EDIT:** changed all ocurrences of _%a_ to _%%a_